# Step-by-step proof of the First Hohenberg-Kohn Theorem in DFT

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, quantum-chemistry, density-functional-theory

I'm trying to proof the [first Hohenberg-Kohn theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_functional_theory#Hohenberg%E2%80%93Kohn_theorems) using the Reductio ad absurdum, but I'm stucked in the last point. First, I know that the eletronic density is:
$${ρ(r)=∑_{i=1}^n|χ_i(r)|²}$$
And,
$$Ψ = ∑_{i=1}^nc_iχ_i(r)$$
The First Theorem states that the external potential $v(r)$ is determined, within a trivial additive constant, by the electron density $ρ(r)$. To proof this, let A and B two systems having the same electron density $ρ(r)$ but two diﬀerent external potentials, so,
$$⟨Ψ_A|H_A|Ψ_B⟩=E_A$$  $$⟨Ψ_B|H_B|Ψ_B⟩=E_B$$
Using the variational principle, and using ${Ψ_A}$ as a trial function for the system B, and ${Ψ_B}$ as a trial function for the system A, we have:
$$⟨Ψ_B|H_A|Ψ_B⟩>E_A \rightarrow ⟨Ψ_B|H_B|Ψ_B⟩-⟨Ψ_B|H_B|Ψ_B⟩+⟨Ψ_B|H_A|Ψ_B⟩>E_A \rightarrow \boldsymbol{E_B +⟨Ψ_B|H_A-H_B|Ψ_B⟩ > E_A} $$
$$⟨Ψ_A|H_B|Ψ_A⟩>E_B \rightarrow ⟨Ψ_A|H_A|Ψ_A⟩-⟨Ψ_A|H_A|Ψ_A⟩+⟨Ψ_A|H_B|Ψ_A⟩>E_B \rightarrow \boldsymbol{E_A -⟨Ψ_A|H_A-H_B|Ψ_A⟩ > E_B} $$
The two Hamiltonians only differ on the potential, so,
$$\boldsymbol{E_B +⟨Ψ_B|V_A-V_B|Ψ_B⟩ > E_A} $$
$$\boldsymbol{E_A -⟨Ψ_A|V_A-V_B|Ψ_A⟩ > E_B} $$
All textbooks and online materials I've read, transform the $⟨Ψ_A|V_A-V_B|Ψ_A⟩$ and $⟨Ψ_B|V_A-V_B|Ψ_B⟩$, in the term $∫(V_A-V_B)ρ(r)dr$, but they didn't show how they do that. So, my question is: How can I do that? I've tried this:
$$⟨Ψ_A|V_A-V_B|Ψ_A⟩ = ∫Ψ_A^*(V_A-V_B)Ψ_Adr = ∫(V_A-V_B)∑_{i=1}^nc_i^*χ_i∑_{i=1}^nc_iχ_idr$$
$$⟨Ψ_A|V_A-V_B|Ψ_A⟩ = ∫(V_A-V_B)∑_{i=1}^n|c_i|^2|χ_i|^2dr$$
How do you deal with the coefficients $|c_i|^2$ to substitute for $ρ(r)$? Or the $ρ(r)$ already has this coefficients and am I writing $ρ(r)$ in a wrong way?

Answer (score 1):

First, let us define the density of a properly normalized and (anti-)symmetrized $N$ particle wave function $\Psi$ as
$$n_\Psi(x) \equiv N\, \int \mathrm{d}x_2\ldots \mathrm{d} x_N \, \Psi^*(x,\ldots,x_N)\, \Psi(x,\ldots,x_N) \quad{.}$$

Second, note that the external potential operator appearing in the many-body Hamiltonian is of the following form:

$$ V \equiv \sum\limits_{i=1}^N v(x_i) \quad{.}$$

Finally, we can see that the expectation value of this external potential in the state $\Psi$ reads

$$ \langle V \rangle_{\Psi} = \sum\limits_{i=1}^N  \int \mathrm{d} x_1 \ldots \mathrm{d} x_N \, v(x_i)\, \Psi^*(x_1,\ldots,x_N)\, \Psi(x_1,\ldots,x_N) $$ which is, due to the (anti-)symmetry of the wave function, equal to
$$  \int \mathrm{d} x \,v(x)\, \underbrace{N\,\int \mathrm{d} x_2 \ldots \mathrm{d} x_N \, \Psi^*(x,\ldots,x_N)\, \Psi(x,\ldots,x_N)}_{=n_\Psi(x)}$$ and thus

$$ \langle V \rangle_{\Psi} = \int \mathrm{d}x \,v(x)\, n_\Psi(x) \quad{.}$$

Comment: Thank you very much, but I had already solved this problem after a few days, I followed more or less what you showed here. I realized that due to the premise that we want to prove, which is $Ψ_A$ and $Ψ_B$ produce the same electronic density, so these two terms will be the same in both equations. However, one thing that helped me to prove this was write the electronic density in the form you showed.